# Create an alias for port

Tags: apache, dns, alias, virtualhost

I really don't know how to solve this problem. I need to load page http://domain.com:12345/ on  address http://sub.domain.com/.

How should I set VirtualHost or Alias on Apache, when I have only one IP address?

Thanks very much.

---

Now I have just this:

ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost domain.com:80
NameVirtualHost sub.domain.com:80
Listen *:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen *:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen *:443
</IfModule>
```

.../sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost sub.domain.com:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        ProxyPass / http://www.domain.com:12345/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domain.com:12345/
</VirtualHost>
```

But this doesn't work. sub.domain.com returns 500 Internal server error.

Comment: I have `<VirtualHost *:3520>` with `ProxyPass / http://local-win.mysite.com:80/` and `ProxyPassReverse / http://local-win.mysite.com:80/`, but local-win.mysite.com still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The solution are Virtual Hosts:

> If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
>   machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
>   use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
>   IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
>
> Please see the documentation at 
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/
>   for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
>
> You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
>   configuration.

And here comes a configuration example:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/www/htdocs/dummy-host.localhost"
    ServerName dummy-host.localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/www/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It does not answer the OP question, how to set up port redirection? The OP also tried to resolve it with VirtualHost (as suggested here), and the question was different.

Comment: @max you can define a port of the virtual host and if required your you can setup a redirect